# Updating a SharedPreferences from another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities. In the first activity, I have a SharedPreferences with a TextView, which displays the amount of data in the SharedPreferences. These codes are written in the onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences coin = getSharedPreferences("saved", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editors editor2 = coin.edit();
editor2.putInt("t", 0).apply();
editor.commit();

TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

Integer a = coin.getInt("t", 0);
name.setText(a.toString());
```

In the second activity, I wanna add 10 points to the data and update the SharedPreferences. These codes are not inside onCreate().

```
SharedPreferences coin = getSharedPreferences("saved", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editors editor2 = coin.edit();

int a = coin.getInt("t", 0);
int b = a + 10;
editor2.putInt("t", Integer.valueOf(b));
```

The problem is, after adding 10 units there is no update in the TextView so I don't even know if the 10 units have been added correctly to SharedPreferences or not.

Please help

Comment: Why are you calling commit() method once apply() is already called?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you would like reflect the final value of `t` in `SharedPreference` in your first activity after its updated in second activity?

To do that, create a function `updateNameTV()` which would contain logic to update the TextView with the value of `t` from `SharedPreference`
and call that function in `onResume()` of the FIRST activity like:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        updateNameTV();

        super.onResume();
    }
```

So when Activity 2 is launched, Activity 1 goes in back of the stack and `onPause()` gets called.. when we return to Activity 1 this activity is pop back and `onStart()` followed by `onResume()` is called.
These are the lifecycle events [more here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

So the plan is, when `onResume()` is called we update the TextView value with the latest `SharedPreference`
And we do that before calling `super.onResume()` such that update is performed before handing over the control to next lifecycle event. Hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: make sure you call commit() while saving the shared preference in activity2.

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: @Ali did this workout for you ? Make sure to use  commit() in 2nd activity because apply() is an async call and sp update may not reflect in 1st activity.. whereas commit is a sync call.. it will commit and then control is passed on to next lifecycle event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your first activity in order to listen to the changes and then update your TextView with the updated value.

Implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your FirstActivity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        // This method will be called when there is a change in SharedPreference
        // Update your textview here
        if(s.equals("t")) {
            Integer a = sharedPreferences.getInt("t", 0);
            name.setText(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

In your FirstActivity's `onStart()` and `onStop()` method, manage the listener:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getSharedPreferences("saved", MODE_PRIVATE).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        getSharedPreferences("saved", MODE_PRIVATE).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

But remember, once you leave your FirstActivity, the listener gets unregistered and you will no longer receive updates. To reflect the updates even after the activity go background, you can just update your textview in your `onStart()` so that when the FirstActivity starts, the textview gets updated with the latest value from SharedPreferences:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences coin = getSharedPreferences("saved", MODE_PRIVATE);
        coin.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        // Also Update the textview here
        Integer a = coin.getInt("t", 0);
        name.setText(a.toString());
    }
```

Now, any update to the preference from anywhere will also change the textview text as soon as the FirstActivity comes into foreground or launches.

Comment: Sorry, so i have to delete the onCreate()?

Comment: Why do you need to delete onCreate() method? I didn't tell that.

Comment: Well i have coded what you write here but still doesn't working

Comment: Sorry, there were some mistakes accessing the shared preferences, before I read your whole code thoroughly. Now, I have updated my answer, it should definitely work.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work again. Can you give me your whatsapp id so i can cummincate better?

Comment: Please help. I need a detailed answer please.